# How can I ignore inherited styles without using "!important"?

Tags: html, css

I don't know if it's possible, but does anyone know how can I ignore all the inherited CSS styles in a new class without using `!important` for each one?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="text">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <span>Date</span>
   <p>Text here...</p>
   <div class="sub-text">
      <p>More text!</p>
      <span>Thanks!</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {width:100%; float:left;}
.text h2 {font-size: 20px;}
.text span {font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;}
.text p {font-size: 12px;}

.sub-text {width: 100%; float: left;}
.sub-text p {I want to ignore all inherit class without use !important}
.sub-text span {I want to ignore all inherit class without use !important}
```

Comment: You should probably use more specific selectors or refactor your DOM structure. You should aim to use `!important` as little as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to target the `span`, `h2` and `p` within `.text` and not within `.sub-text` you should use the selector `>`

Like this:

```
.text > h2 { font-size: 20px; }
```

That will target all `h2` that are a direct child of `.text`.

Also check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp,

**And this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/YguBP/)**.

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
.text {width:100%; float:left;}
.text > h2 {font-size: 20px;}
.text > span {font-size: 12px; font-style: italic;}
.text > p {font-size: 12px;}

.sub-text {width: 100%; float: left;}
.sub-text p {/* there is nothing inherited now */}
.sub-text span {/* there is nothing inherited now */}
```

So the `>` means that only direct children of .text get the css...

Answer (score 0):

CSS uses precedence, so any css written after the before css should overwrite. If it doesn't then that means you aren't being specific enough with your statements.